# Airflow transfer data between tasks without storing data in between stages

Tags: airflow

I would like to know how to transfer data between tasks without storing them in between. 
Attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpOjP.png) one can find the flow of tasks. As of now I am storing the output csv files of each task as a file in my local machine and fetching this csv file again as an input to next task. I wanted to know if there is any otherway to pass data between tasks without storing it after each task. I researched a bit and came across **Xcoms**. I wanted to make sure if **Xcoms** are the right way to achieve this or am I wrong. I could not find any practical examples. Any help is appreciated as I am just a newbie in airflow started couple of days

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is no, tasks require data to be at rest before moving to the nest task. Xcom's are most suited to short strings that can be shared between tasks (file directories, object names, etc.). Your current flow of storing the data in csv files between tasks is the optimal way of running your flow.

Answer (score 1):

XCom is intended for sharing little pieces of information, like the len of the sql table, any specific values or things like that. It is not made for sharing dataframes (which can be huge) because the shared information is written in the metadata database.

So either you keep exporting the csv to your computer (or uploading them somewhere), for reading it in the next Operator, or you combine the operators into one.

Comment: Hi @Javier López Tomás , Thanks for your comment on this. I understood storing csv files in between the tasks is a way to this. Also you mentioned about combining operators - what does this exactly mean? Does this mean combining multiple tasks to one task ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, although that depends on what kind of tasks you are using. If they are PtyhonOperator, you can easily combine the code of some of them into one single Operator (1 task). Anyway, if making that you are losing readability, it's maybe not worth it and is better to keep with your initial strategy

Comment: Thank a lot @ Javier López Tomás ! It is much clear now

Comment: could you please help me here if possible - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013161/airflow-hdfssensor-alternative-for-python-3] I am not finding any alternate.